# How to tell CMake to recursively search include directory when specificying INCLUDE_PATH in CMakeCache.txt

Tags: cmake, ncurses

I have recently built ncurses-6.1 using the source code and would like to configure my build of STIR (software for tomographic image reconstruction) to use this recent version of ncurses. However, I cannot figure out how to tell cmake to search subdirectories in the include folder. When specifying the ncurses include path in the CMakeCache.txt file:

> CURSES_INCLUDE_PATH:PATH=/home/matthew/Programs/ncurses/ncurses-6.1-build/include

I receive the following error upon running make in my STIR-build directory:

```
In file included from /home/matthew/Programs/stir/STIR/src/display/gen.c:21:0:
/home/matthew/Programs/stir/STIR/src/display/gen.h:111:10: fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory
 #include <curses.h>             /* for getch */
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

However, if I specify the subdirectory:

> CURSES_INCLUDE_PATH:PATH=/home/matthew/Programs/ncurses/ncurses-6.1-build/include/ncurses

then I receive the following error:

```
In file included from /home/matthew/Programs/stir/STIR/src/display/gen.h:111:0,
                 from /home/matthew/Programs/stir/STIR/src/display/screengen.c:23:
/home/matthew/Programs/ncurses/ncurses-6.1-build/include/ncurses/curses.h:60:10: fatal error: ncurses/ncurses_dll.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ncurses/ncurses_dll.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

The build succeeds when I copy the header files from the subdirectory directly into the include folder (alongside the subdirectory). How can I tell cmake to recursively look in the subdirectory?

Comment: why do you update CMakeCache.txt? I think you should add find_package(ncurses REQUIRED) and target_link_libraries / target_include_directories with those provided by the find_package statement in your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I have only ever built programs using cmake from the terminal while configuring with -D<option> and never by updating CMakeLists.txt, likely due to the instructions I've read in README files and the nature of the options being set. I will look into learning how to do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

CMake does not provide such a feature directly.  You could write a `file(GLOB_RECURSE ..)` command to gather all directories under a given directory into a list and then issue a `include_directories()` command based on that list.  e.g.

```
set(myDesiredRootForHeaderFileSearch ~/special/include/path)
file(GLOB my_include_directories ${myDesiredRootForHeaderFileSearch})
include_directories(${my_include_directories})
```

The `GLOB` command gets directories, so this is good.

You could also use this very helpful macro which I found on a forum:

```
MACRO(HEADER_DIRECTORIES return_list)
    FILE(GLOB_RECURSE new_list *.h)
    SET(dir_list "")
    FOREACH(file_path ${new_list})
        GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(dir_path ${file_path} PATH)
        SET(dir_list ${dir_list} ${dir_path})
    ENDFOREACH()
    LIST(REMOVE_DUPLICATES dir_list)
    SET(${return_list} ${dir_list})
ENDMACRO()

HEADER_DIRECTORIES(header_list)

include_directories(${header_list}
```

as suggested in this post [Link to post](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-June/050674.html)